# Swift - iOS UTC date and time set with the device date and time format with offset

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to iOS.

I am getting time in UTC YYYY-mm-dd H:i:s format. I want to format and offset the date and time according to the device region.

### Code

```
let utcdatestring  = cat.created
let localdate = Validator.UTCToLocal(date: utcdatestring, fromFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", toFormat: Constants.dateformat)
let localtime = Validator.UTCToLocal(date: utcdatestring, fromFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", toFormat: Validator.gettimeformat())

let locale = Locale.current.identifier
let formater = DateFormatter()
formater.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
formater.locale =  Locale(identifier: locale)
let showdate = formater.date(from: localdate)

let tformater = DateFormatter()
tformater.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
tformater.locale =  Locale(identifier: locale)
let showtime = tformater.date(from: localtime)
```

I found some way on apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter) but not sure how to implement in my code.

### Reference

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
 
let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 118800)
 
// US English Locale (en_US)
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
print(dateFormatter.string(from: date)) // Jan 2, 2001
 
// French Locale (fr_FR)
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")
print(dateFormatter.string(from: date)) // 2 janv. 2001
 
// Japanese Locale (ja_JP)
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ja_JP")
print(dateFormatter.string(from: date)) // 2001/01/02
```

> **Question:**
>
> How can I convert UTC date and time to the device date and time format with offset

Comment: What's wrong with using the code in the documentation?

Comment: @Sweeper as I said new to Swift with no experience, not getting an idea of how to implement it. What I mean is how can I convert my code according to document one to pass region dynamically.

Comment: Just don't set the `locale` manually. It's automatically set to the user's locale.

Comment: Do you mean this? `ormater.locale =  Locale(identifier: locale)` to `ormater.locale =  Locale()` ? I am sorry being stupid.

Comment: I mean you should delete that line completely.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks a lot. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
let utcdatestring  = cat.created
let localdate = Validator.UTCToLocal(date: utcdatestring, fromFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", toFormat: Constants.dateformat)
let localtime = Validator.UTCToLocal(date: utcdatestring, fromFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", toFormat: Validator.gettimeformat())

let formater = DateFormatter()
formater.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
let showdate = formater.date(from: localdate)

let tformater = DateFormatter()
tformater.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
let showtime = tformater.date(from: localtime)
```

try like this. the locale will be set automatially i guess

Comment: But when you are setting date format `formater.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"` Will this automatically change the format based on the device?